# Add htmlparser, htmlnode to project

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, web

What should I do to add to my project HTMLParser, htmlnode,...?
Because the add (the. H and. M) but I get the following error:

libxml/HTMLparser.h file not found!

tx.

Answer (score 6):

1. You have to include in "Build Phases" under "Link Binary With Libraries" the libxml.dylib
2. Add
   **${SDK_DIR}/usr/include/libxml2**
   to
   "Header Search Paths"

Comment: This should be "Header Search Paths", not "User Header Search Paths".  The former uses angle-bracket includes, like <libxml/blah>, whilst the latter uses quoted includes, like "libxml/blah".

Answer (score 3):

For me solution was to add $(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2 to "Header Search Paths"